# SQL order by DATE DESC + group on other Column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have tried a lot of different grouping and ordering syntax but I am really struggling to get what I need.

I am trying to order by DATE DESC, but I also want the PROJECTS to stick together (no matter what date order the projects would fall in)

Here is the data I am working with currently.

```
ACCOUNT PROJECT DATE
P050    D       2015-07-23
P057    C       2015-04-30
P057    C       2015-05-29
S001    A       2015-05-30
S001    A       2015-06-30
T004    B       2015-06-30
T004    B       2015-04-30
T004    B       2015-06-30
S001    A       2015-07-31
T004    B       2015-08-10
T004    B       2015-01-19
S001    A       2015-07-23
P057    C       2015-06-29
```

Comment: For the example data-set you have provided, please could you give example-expected-results?  The phrase `I also want the PROJECTS to stick together` is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: Could you provide the *desired output*, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the maximum date for each project and then join this to the original table.  You can then order by the maximum (or minimum if you like) date first, then the project, and then the specific activity:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select project, max(date) as maxd
      from table
      group by project
     ) tt
     on t.project = tt.project
order by tt.maxd desc, tt.project, t.date desc;
```